# Show Month with the Highest Quantity Sold

Tags: mysql, sql, select, database

I need to show the month with the highest number of quantity sold.
I don't know how to do that. Please help thank you.
I have:

> id, prod_name, price, q_sold, month

the q_sold must sum up with the number of month input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order your result by the sum and take only the first entry with `limit 1`

```
select `month`, sum(q_sold) as sold_sum
from your_table
group by `month`
order by sold_sum desc
limit 1
```

Comment: The q_sold must only sum up when the month are all same.

Comment: Yes, the `group by month` is doing that.

Comment: i got undefined index for q_sold

Comment: that sounds like a PHP error. Are you running this query in code? Please verify the query in a SQL tool first.

Comment: `<?php
include 'connect.php';


$bogart=mysqli_query($con," SELECT  `month`, sum(q_sold) as sold_sum
FROM  `samsung_store` group by `month` order by sold_sum desc
LIMIT 1 ") or die (mysql_error());

$count=mysqli_num_rows($bogart);

while($baragan=mysqli_fetch_array($bogart)){

if($count % 2 == 0){
$color="#EDEDED";
$count--;
}
else{
$color="white";
$count--;
}
?>

 <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
      <td> <?php echo $baragan['q_sold']?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $baragan['month'] ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>`

Comment: You should run the query in myPHPAdmin or another SQL tool. If it works and you don't get your PHP code working, then you can ask another question about that task on Stack Overflow.

Comment: it's just the php that don't get it right. BTW thanks i'm a newbie in SQL that's why. Haha

Comment: Your welcome. But I can't help you with your PHP code. I don't program in PHP.